# Convert streaming dataflow pipeline having kafka as source to batch pipeline in GCP

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming dataflow pipeline in which kafka is acting as input and data is loaded to bigquery. As this operation is expensive and  KafkaIO source returns unbounded collection of Kafka records so is there any way in which this dataflow pipeline can be converted to batch mode with kafka as source .
Below is the sample code

// Existing streaming pipeline reading from Kafka and writing to BigQuery

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

pipeline
    .apply("ReadFromKafka", KafkaIO.read().withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092").withTopics(Arrays.asList("topic")))
    .apply("TransformData", ... )
    .apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to("project:dataset.table").withSchema(...));
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "unbounded / expensive". What resource utilization dashboards are you looking at? The Kafka consumer will poll only 500 records at a time, then they're all processed in a batch (written to BQ), then you get up to 500 again. This happens automatically

Comment: @OneCricketeer. unbounded here means "never-ending data streams with no beginning or end". Expensive means streaming dataflow will be running all the time rather than on schduled or need basis . so over the time it will incur more cost. So that's why i want to change this to batch mode with minimal changes

Comment: I belive that is impossible. Having an `unbounded` source automatically results in a streaming Dataflow pipeline.

Comment: Spark has batch streaming that you can run in Dataproc / GKE. I don't think Beam/Dataflow does batch, as mentioned